# How to write a mod_rewrite rule to look for an image in a specific folder?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to write a rule to redirect any image file to a specific folder. Namely "images"

```
RewriteCond $1 ^(.*\.jpg|.*\.gif|.*\.bmp)
```

That will match all the imag, the the rerwrite part is confusing me.
I want that

```
Http://domain.com/path/controller/view/image.jpg
http://domain.com/any/path/that/i/want/image.jpg
```

to load the file

```
http://domain.com/iamges/image.jpg
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# prevent endless loops
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !images/

# capture only the filename 
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*\.jpg|.*\.gif|.*\.bmp) images/$1 [L,R]
```

The R option in the [L,R] is forcing a visible rewrite - if you want it to appear that the image is coming from the request url then just use [L]

Take a look at the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for more details

Comment: thanks a lot man..
I actually got something along the same line.. but the prevent endless lopp part that is causing me some problems( i don't have it ).. and your example solved my problem...